# How to enable speech recognition in electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, speech-recognition, webkitspeechrecognition

I have a chatbot which runs in electron and I need to add speech to text there. I used window.SpeechRecognition and window.webkitSpeechRecognition but it seems now chrome is not supporting to speech recognition in electron. Is there a way that I can enable speech to text in electron. Below is my code which I've tried.

```
function listen() {
    let mic = document.getElementById('mic');
    mic.style.color = 'red';
    mic.className = 'animated pulse infinite';
    let SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
    var hear = new SpeechRecognition();
    hear.continuous = false;
    hear.lang = 'en-IN';
    hear.start();
    hear.onresult = function (e) {
        mic.style.color = 'black';
        mic.className = '';
        userVoiceText = e.results[0][0].transcript;
        hear.stop();
        createSender(userVoiceText);
        respond(userVoiceText);
    }
}
```

This is a must need requirement for my app. Suggestions for any workaround or API is appreciated.

Comment: Last time I looked at this (well over a year ago) the support was OS-specific. Do you have a reference to say if chrome has completely dropped support?

Comment: check this link, https://github.com/noffle/electron-speech "It seems that Google has shut down the Chrome Speech API for use in shell environments like Electron". DO you have any idea to use speech to text in electron?

Comment: it was reported as fixed in electron 9.x (https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23813) but i cant get it working too

Comment: What's the update now? @Tobias

Comment: What's the update now? @shamila

Comment: What's the update now? @DarrenCook

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this in your main process:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features', 'WebSpeechAPI');
```